# Connecting to PostgreSQL container from another container with docker-compose

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to fetch data from a REST API `https://www.opentopodata.org/` and insert the fetched json formatted data meanwhile putting the relevant data to columns that I've been designed. However, because of I'm a newbie and there is no concrete example except Flask applications, I couldn't figure it out how to configure my `docker-compose.yml` file which didn't work properly.
How can I configure the `docker-compose.yml` properly.

I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows 10 OS.

- Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.1-alpine

RUN apk update \
  && apk add \
    build-base \
    postgresql \
    postgresql-dev \
    libpq
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./requirements.txt .
COPY ./base.py .
COPY ./elev.py .
COPY ./downloader.py .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["python","base.py"]
CMD ["python","elev.py"]
CMD ["python","downloader.py"]
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000 : 5000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db


  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: sqlalchemy
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

- my `base.py` file in order to connect to PostgreSQL container

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# engine = create_engine('postgresql://usr:pass@localhost:5432/sqlalchemy')
engine = create_engine('postgresql://usr:pass@{}:5432/database'.format('db'))
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
```

- my `elev.py` file in order to define the `Elevation` table

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Date, Float
from base import Base


class Elevation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'elevation'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat = Column(Float)
    lng = Column(Float)
    elevation= Column(Float)

    def __init__(self, lat, lng, elevation):
        self.lat = lat
        self.lng = lng
        self.elevation = elevation
```

- my `downloader.py` file in order to fetch data with `requests` module for corresponding latitude and longitude values within a loop.

```
import requests
import json
import time
from elev import Elevation
from base import Session, engine, Base

# 2 - generate database schema
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)



#create a new session """airports can be added"""
session = Session()

lat=[40,35]
lng=[49,42]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in lat:
        for x in lng:
            url = "https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/aster30m?locations=" + str(i) +',' + str(x)
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.text
            parsed = json.loads(data)
            # add data to postgresql table 
            elevation_api=Elevation(lat=parsed['results'][0]['location']['lat'],
                                    lng=parsed['results'][0]['location']['lng'],
                                    elevation=parsed['results'][0]['elevation'])

            session.add(elevation_api)
            session.commit()
            print(parsed)
            time.sleep(3)

session.close()
```

Comment: For the community to be able to help you better, please be more specific on what is the problem/error you are facing.

Comment: If you list more than 1 `CMD` then only the last `CMD` will take effect. This is reported as a warning if you lint your `Dockerfile` with the [Haskell Dockerfile Linter](https://hadolint.github.io/hadolint/) i.e. `docker run --rm -i hadolint/hadolint < Dockerfile`.

Comment: @camba1 my problem is I couldn't figure out how to code ```docker-compose.yml``` correctly.

Comment: @masseyb You're right, I totally forgot that.

Comment: @BerkeŞentürk if you need all three to run in order you could add i.e. a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script that executes the `python` scripts and set that as your containers `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: @masseyb Yes, I want to use scripts in order. I will apply ```docker-entrypoint.sh```